# Develop Autoware packages under ade environment

Tags: ros2, docker, ssh, clion, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I develop custom packages within ade docker container? I need remote host credentials to set connection between clion and debugger inside ade container. SSH service is disabled and won't start.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381967/develop-autoware-packages-under-ade-environment/) by [definitive](https://answers.ros.org/users/57454/definitive/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2021-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question doesn't seem to be specific to ROS, so you may want to look into how others in general run ssh servers in containers:

https://docs.docker.com/samples/running_ssh_service

That said, I find VSCode's support for remote container development a little more polished than with Clion.

- https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2020/01/using-docker-with-clion
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers

---

Originally posted by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) with karma: 1094 on 2021-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The intended workflow with ADE is more that you run your editor/IDE and other tools *inside* of the ADE container, so you don't have to work with remote hosts and such. Typically, you would create a custom volume containing the tool, which ADE then allows you to load together with the base image. See the documentation which describes this process for the Atom editor:

https://ade-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/create-custom-volume.html

The full setup for that can also be found in the following Git repository:

https://gitlab.com/ApexAI/ade-atom

And there is one for VSCode as well:

https://gitlab.com/ApexAI/ade-vscode

To use CLion like that you will have to create a similar setup yourself, I'm not aware of one already existing.

---

Originally posted by [sgvandijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/72841/sgvandijk/) with karma: 649 on 2021-07-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1